# awk: adding a record separator to all rows

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to reformat some structured data, like below, into a delimited tabular format. The number of rows for each record is variable, but the number of columns is not (it's actually five not three).

```
title1
data data data
data data data
data data data
title22
data data data
data data data
title333
data data data
```

Result should look like this (an extra column for the record separator):

```
title1 data data data
title1 data data data
title1 data data data
title22 data data data
title22 data data data
title333 data data data
```

Using `awk` the record separator is easy enough to regex with `"title[0-9]+"`, but I am unable to add this to the rows that correspond to each separated record.

```
awk '{RS="title[0-9]+"}{print RT $0}' file
```

Doesn't have to be `awk`, if `sed` or something else works better.

Comment: In GNU awk, as you must be using, RS is the Record Separator regexp and RT is the string that matched that regexp. So your code `awk '{RS="title[0-9]+"}{print RT $0}' file` is finding the `title...` that occurs **after** the current record (i.e. the string that separates it from the next record) and then printing it **before** the current record. It's also printing it once for the record when you actually want to print it once per line of each record. See [@RavinderSingh13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54495724/1745001) for how best to really do this (and it's portable to all awks).

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^title/{val=$0;next} {print val,$0}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -E '/^title/h;//d;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' file
```

Save the title line in the hold space, otherwise append the title line to the record line and re-arrange it so that the title comes first.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk for a generic answer..

```
awk '  { if(NF>1) {print title,$0 } else { title=$0} } '
```

with inputs:

```
$ cat drcatfish.txt
title1
data data data
data data data
data data data
title22
data data data
data data data
title333
data data data

$ awk '  { if(NF>1) {print title,$0 } else { title=$0} } ' drcatfish.txt
title1 data data data
title1 data data data
title1 data data data
title22 data data data
title22 data data data
title333 data data data

$
```